# Publish android library to nexus with gradle

Tags: android, maven, gradle

I'm trying to publish my android library to nexus with gradle so that others people can use the code. But It does not work and return the error message:

```
> Could not publish configuration 'archives'
```

> java.io.IOException: Could not PUT http://`my-server`/nexus/content/repositories/snapsho
>   ts/TestLib/testlibdemo/unspecified/testlibdemo-unspecified.aar. Received status code 400 from server:
>    Bad Request

Does the gradle supported that publishing the aar to Maven Central?

I'm a noob in gradle. Here is my build file.

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
}
}

apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'android-library'


repositories {
mavenCentral()
flatDir name: "dist", dirs: "dist"
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 8
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}

uploadArchives {
repositories {
    maven {
        credentials {
            username "admin"
            password "admin123"
        }
        url "http://myserver/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots"
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is relevant for Android but for plain old Java I needed to add the following to deploy to a Nexus repository using http.

```
configurations {
    deployJars
}

dependencies {
    deployJars "org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-http:2.2"
}
```

I have this in the subprojects of my top level build.gradle for a multi-project build.

My uploadArchives also looks slightly different to yours with

```
uploadArchives {
    repositories.mavenDeployer {
        repository (url: "<repository url>") {
            authentication(userName: "<username>", password: "<password>")
        }
    }
}
```

I actually have the items in <> as properties in the gradle.properties file so I can override them on the command line, specifically the username and password. That way when I build from Team City I am not embedding my credentials into a file that colleagues can see. Team City allows me to store those values as build variables that are displayed as ******.